# pi4 won't return after reboot connected switch?

Tags: pi-4, ethernet-port, reboot

I have PI4 that connected to router
after I reboot ONLY the router ,  I can see the pi is still connected to the router - but I can't reach it. The pi have static ip.

No ping to the pi  , disable \ enable the ethernet port - still nothing
only after reboot the pi (using "sudo reboot" with connected keyboard" ) it return to work

why is it?

when I look at the /var/log/messages.1  I see this:(this is when I lost connection , my router reboot at 03:30)

```
Jan  9 03:30:14 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.423473] broken atomic modeset userspace detected, disabling atomic
```

and when I look at the syslog I get this:

```
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[453]: eth0: carrier acquired
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[453]: eth0: IAID 32:9e:4a:db
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[453]: eth0: adding address fe80::d84:c1e8:b49b:f39f
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[387]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d84:c1e8:b49b:f39f.
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[387]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[387]: Registering new address record for fe80::d84:c1e8:b49b:f39f on eth0.*.
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi kernel: [86379.342390] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
Jan  9 03:30:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[453]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jan  9 03:30:10 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.045283] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet clock
Jan  9 03:30:10 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.045303] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
Jan  9 03:30:10 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.045328] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet-wol clock
Jan  9 03:30:10 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.045349] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: failed to get enet-eee clock
Jan  9 03:30:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Jan  9 03:30:11 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.671894] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII
Jan  9 03:30:11 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.672102] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
Jan  9 03:30:21 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: carrier acquired
Jan  9 03:30:21 raspberrypi kernel: [   19.034816] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
Jan  9 03:30:21 raspberrypi kernel: [   19.034858] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jan  9 03:30:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: IAID 32:9e:4a:db
Jan  9 03:30:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: adding address fe80::d84:c1e8:b49b:f39f
Jan  9 03:30:22 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[405]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::d84:c1e8:b49b:f39f.
Jan  9 03:30:22 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[405]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan  9 03:30:22 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[405]: Registering new address record for fe80::d84:c1e8:b49b:f39f on eth0.*.
Jan  9 03:30:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: probing address 10.0.0.100/24
Jan  9 03:30:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[405]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.0.0.100.
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[405]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[405]: Registering new address record for 10.0.0.100 on eth0.IPv4.
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: received approval for 10.0.0.100
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: adding route to 10.0.0.0/24
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: adding default route via 10.0.0.1
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: received approval for 10.0.0.100
Jan  9 03:30:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[452]: eth0: received approval for 10.0.0.100
```

so what is the problem?

Thanks ,

Comment: How exactly RPi is configured to acquire an IP address? If that is DHCP, probably there is some timeout in action (RPi sees a link, performs a discovery and times out trying to get a config while router isn't ready and still is booting). Try to read logs on RPi, what it does when it "sees" router gone.

Comment: the pi have static ip ,

Comment: Static IP addresses are *usually* a bad idea. Could you explain why you have chosen to use one instead of relying on the default (DHCP address assignment) which works most of the time?

Comment: Ok, asking again, what is in the logfile in the instant of disconnect/failed reconnect? Also, when it works, there must be an ARP entry with RPi's IP addres adn its MAC address. When it doesn't ping, what ARP entry do you have corresponding to RPi's IP address? // @Seamus, what you wrote, seems wrong to me. Static IP is not "usually bad". In this particular case, using static addresses **is** an appropriate way to isolate a problem. Until everything works fine with all static addresses, DHCP service shall not be introduced into the network anyway.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: You are entitled to [your opinion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVCtkzIXYzQ), but there are a lot of questions here from people inexperienced in networking, who break things when they apply fixed IP addresses. That said, I'll look forward to seeing your answer here.

Comment: I use static because I use NAT from my router to the PI . also the device is not near me to check what was the problem , so I can't tell you what in the log. I ask someone to reboot it , and then i will see . which log file should I search ?

Comment: So, do you have an ARP table entry for 10.0.0.100? Does RPi have ARP entries for other hosts, most important, 10.0.0.1? On RPi (and on other Linux) you can check that with `arp -n` or `ip neigh`.

Comment: this I can only while I have access to the pi , which I didn't have . I had to ask someone to reboot the PI - then I mange to connect and see the logs I have post.